# The playback of "audiolayers" and "audio_service" is interrupted by other media applications

Tags: flutter, audio-service

I use `audiolayers` and `audio_service` plays audio. It works well. When I open other audio applications (such as Apple Music) to play music, my app will stop playing. This is OK. But when I return to my app to query the current playing status, it is still playing.

This is my code：

```
Container(
    height: 60.w,
    width: 60.w,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.w),
        gradient: const LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [Color(0xFFD54381), Color(0xFF7644AD)]),
        ),
        child: StreamBuilder<PlaybackState>(
           stream: customAudioHandler?.playbackState,
           builder: (context, snapshot) {
             final playing = snapshot.data?.playing ?? false;
             return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => _playOrPause(context, playing),
                  child: Icon(
                    playing ? FontIcons.stop : FontIcons.play,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 40.w,
                 ),
              );
           },
        ),
   ),
```

I try to use `WidgetsBindingObserver`

such：

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        var audioHandlerState = customAudioHandler?.playbackState.value.playing;
        var audioPlayerState = audioPlayer.state;

        // print true
        debugPrint('didChangeAppLifecycleState-resumed: $audioHandlerState'); 

        // print PlayerState.playing
        debugPrint('didChangeAppLifecycleState-resumed: $audioPlayerState'); 

        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        break;
    }
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }
```

Their output status is playing

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: audio_service provides interrupt notification? How to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app's audio session is interrupted by another app's audio session, you will want to be notified in some way so that you can update your app's state (in your case, broadcast a new `playbackState` with `playing=false`).

You can access the audio session via the Flutter [audio_session](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_session) package. With your instance of the session, you can listen to when your session is interrupted by another app:

```dart
session.interruptionEventStream.listen((event) {
  if (event.begin) {
    switch (event.type) {
      case AudioInterruptionType.duck:
        // Here you could lower the volume
        break;
      case AudioInterruptionType.pause:
      case AudioInterruptionType.unknown:
        // Here you should pause your audio
        player.pause();
        // AND ALSO broadcast the new state
        playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(playing: false));
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

The official audio_service example also demonstrates this use case, although with a different audio player plugin (just_audio) which uses audio_session under the hood to make this use case easier.

Comment: I have used audio_session package to handle this situation, thanks for the suggestion